# node.js ejs include partials, and in the main, can't find the variable defined in the partial file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, include, ejs

this is my code to be included in the main ejs file.

```
<%

const IDP_URL = "http://idp.com:8082";
const SP_ID = "testing";
const SP_SECRET = "XRRpYIoMtaJC8hFLfUN7Bw==";
const TOKEN_VERIFY_FAIL_URL ="/exsignon/sso/token_verify_fail.ejs";
const LOGINUSER_REDIRECT_URL = "/exsignon/sso/sso_loginuser.jsp";
const ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = "/exsignon/sample/main.jsp";

%>
```

and in my main ejs file I'm trying to call `sp_ID`, and won't recognize and throws an error that `sp_id` is not defined, I've used many types of includes(`<% include filename %>`, `<%- include filename %>`, `<%- include (filename) %>`) and etc

any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post code of main.ejs file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wrap all your javascript code in <% %> tags

```
<% const IDP_URL = "http://idp.com:8082"; %>
<% const SP_ID = "testing"; %>
<% const SP_SECRET = "XRRpYIoMtaJC8hFLfUN7Bw=="; %>
<% const TOKEN_VERIFY_FAIL_URL ="/exsignon/sso/token_verify_fail.ejs"; %>
<% const LOGINUSER_REDIRECT_URL = "/exsignon/sso/sso_loginuser.jsp"; %>
<% const ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = "/exsignon/sample/main.jsp"; %>
```